# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<AppUser | null>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppUser>'

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have an authentication service in my code and there is a problem with this lines:

```
get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser> {
  return this.user$
    .switchMap(user => {
      if (user) return this.userService.get(user.uid);

     return Observable.of(null);
    });
  }
}
```

It is almost fully red-underlined by VSCode. I have a compilation error:

[image]

But my app seems to be still working and I had a similar console error compared to the compilation error but it passed away somehow.

When I tryed to modify the second return line to:

```
 return this.Observable.of(null);
```

then I get this console error:

[image]

I found a solution for this as adding safe navigation operator '?' can solve this and I added it to the parts where it should be but it could not resolve the console message. Please, help me in this case. Thx!

Comment: `get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser | null>` add this inside return type of appUser$().

Comment: It is mainly an 'error' raised by TSLint for strict types. You have to redefine the declaration to explicitly allow `null` values. You can see more info here: https://blog.angular.io/angular-cli-strict-mode-c94ba5965f63 and if you want to disable it, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566377/turning-off-strict-mode-in-angular

Comment: @GauranDhorda: it helped, thx! But... an other compilation error raised in my bs-navbar.component.ts with this lines:   constructor(private auth: AuthService) { 
    auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser);
  }     and console error message says:    Error: src/app/bs-navbar/bs-navbar.component.ts:14:40 - error TS2322: Type 'AppUser | null' is not assignable to type 'AppUser | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'AppUser | undefined'.
    14     auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser);

Comment: @LPedro7 `this.appUser : <AppUser | null>` type should be like this in component .

Comment: @GaurangDhorda you should provide those as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly type your function return type with current type of variable..

```
  get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser | null>
   // add this to your return type of function.
```

Your second type error you need to correct type of varibalr like this..

```
  this.appUser : <AppUser | null>
```

This way you can have your well structured type system around with you.