# Typescript error: Property [name] does not exist on Type [Object]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am reading an Angular 9 book and the author has updates online for Angular 11.
I started getting the error:
"Property [name] does not exist on Type [Object]"
for code like

```
let myData = new Object();
myData.name = "Adam";
myData.weather = "sunny";
```

Everyone seems to be saying to create an interface to fix this.
But I am wondering if there is a simple way to turn this off in tsConfig.json so I can follow along with the examples in the book.

Comment: maybe disabling strict mode will help, try read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566377/turning-off-strict-mode-in-angular

Comment: How about `let myData = {};` instead?

Answer (score 2):

myData is an Object.

You can do one of these:

1.

```js
let myData: any = new Object();
```

2. 

```js
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
  weather: string;
}

let myData: MyInterface = new Object() as MyInterface;
myData.name = "Adam";
myData.weather = "sunny";
```

3. 

```js
class MyType {
  name: string;
  weather: string;
}

let myData2 = new MyType()
myData2.name = "Adam";
myData2.weather = "sunny"
```